# Unwanted top margin on TextView with horizontal linear layout

Tags: android-studio, button, textview, android-linearlayout

Can Somebody explain why there is a margin above the textview with this layout? This seems like a bug to me. I can not find a way to remove this so that the TextView and Button start at the same height

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_TimeSpan"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="From: 15.05.2023 00:00\nTo: 17.05.2023 23:59\n\n" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change"
        android:onClick="B_ChangeTimestamp_onClick" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Here a dirty fix on the TextView Element:

```
android:layout_marginTop="-14dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
```

Edit: The margin offset changes when a button has two lines of text to 10dp

Comment: Add `android:baselineAligned="false"` to the opening `<LinearLayout>` tag. `LinearLayout`'s default behavior in horizontal mode aligns `View`s by their baselines. For `TextView` and `Button` (which is just a specialized `TextView`), that's defined as the baseline of the first line of text.

Comment: thanks that worked. a little bit weird that this is needed for something that simple but ... yeah that just so android

Comment: I noticed it only happens when the first view (the TextView) has 2 lines and the second view 1 line. If the 2 views have the same lines, that extra top margin doesn't appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add android:baselineAligned="false" to the opening  tag. LinearLayout's default behavior in horizontal mode aligns Views by their baselines. For TextView and Button (which is just a specialized TextView), that's defined as the baseline of the first line of text.

Here is the answer from Mike.

Comment: I couldn't thank you enough Mike and you for asking the question because I was this close to give up